# Electron app rendering images incorrectly

Tags: javascript, electron

I've written up an electron app which acts as the user interface for a smart mirror (i.e. displays the time, date, etc.) but right now it currently displays the image of the weather icon more than once, and I am not sure where in the code I made the error in.

Here is a link to the github [repo](https://github.com/jadech32/mirrortest) since its too long to paste in here. JavaScript code for all functions is in [scripts.js](https://github.com/jadech32/mirrortest/blob/master/js/scripts.js)

Thank you in advance.

For reference, this is what it is currently [doing](https://image.prntscr.com/image/qwwL1bQQQsGHsPcgsXMaAQ.png) and [this](https://image.prntscr.com/image/xWSIfVC1TkC5_gnwTZHCJw.png) is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, I think it's the `setInterval(renderImage, 10000)` line in your `render()` method. It looks like it's adding a new image every 10 seconds.

On another note, the code in your repo is very poorly formatted. I'd recommend adding a linter, or at the very least setting something in your editor config for more consistent formatting.

Comment: Ok so I figured it out. setTimeout will not make this issue, but IIRC the two methods only differ in how the function delays before executing the next time, so I i'm not quite sure how setInterval caused this problem.. any ideas?

Comment: `setTimeout()` will execute the function only once, while `setInterval()` will execute the function repeatedly.